# Htmlentities but stil match bbcode

Tags: php, security, textarea, bbcode

I'm using http://jbbcode.com/ and I don't know how to use HTML entities for that.

If I use it before checking for BBCodes, the characters [ , ] and / will be converted into `&whatever;`.

If I use it after I check, jBBCode change for me `[b]Bold text[/b]` with `<b>Bold text</b>`. Now HTML entities and convert all.

I only want to sanitize this textarea field.

The all textarea value I insert into database by using …nothing. Only Prepared statements (PDO).

What can I do?

Comment: You could convert it first, then use str_replace to put the characters you need back in.

Comment: Hmm... i don't no if it's working, but i'll try. Thank's !